# What is this electrical component?

Tags: components

Well that's a quite simple question. I tried my chance with Google Images without success and tried some lists of images to be able to know what is this component. But I don't find it and there is nothing written on it.

[image]

Comment: Short Circuits, Volume 1 or 2 or 3 by Jaycar Pty Ltd.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is [Light dependent resistor (LDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor).

Its similar to a normal resistor, but the resistance decreases with increasing light intensity.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you O.Blue I can put a sticker on it now :)

Comment: If the answer seems good to you, don't forget to accept it (button just below the up/down vote arrows). It allows to mark the question as answered

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that these are generally based on Cadmium Sulfide (CdS), and are therefore not RoHS-compliant (Cadmium is on the no-no list). Use [ambient light sensor](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=ambient+light+sensor) (the generic term) for plenty of RoHS-compliant options.

Comment: Do they only work for visible light or can you get ones for ultraviolet, infrared, etc light as well?

Comment: @MiximG wanted to do it straightly but had to wait "10 minutes" and had to go, so it's done only now.

Comment: @Pikamander2 the vast majority work in the visible light region. You'd probably want a different sensor for other regions (photodiode, etc.)

Comment: @Pikamander2 I know this is a couple years late, but a cadmium selenide photocell will work for visible light down to about 700nm wavelength (deep red, nearly infrared) and any higher energy (shorter wavelength) light. Pure cadmium sulfide cells won't work for red or yellow light, but they'll work for green light and any higher energy light. It depends on the bandgap of the semiconductor used in the photocell.